# Как исправить проблему с одинаковыми MAC адресами по проводному интернету?

Tags: сеть, mac-address

Недавно в общаге сделали фильтрацию по MAC адресу. Взял MAC адрес соседа (так как у него есть доступ в сети, а у моего компа нет). Но так как два одинаковых адреса в базе, "пакеты" идут то к нему, то ко мне.... и соответственно нельзя нормально пользоваться. Можно ли это как-то исправить оставляя два одинаковых MAC адреса?

Comment: Администратор сам исправит. Обнаружит что маки сдублированы и забанит их.

Comment: Соседу нужно настроить раздачу интернета по wifi или проводу